# Problems changing project root in CLion

Tags: cmake, clion

I have a project for which all the real source/header files are in an external directory. I want the ability to get code completion, jump to definitions, and Find Usages (of member functions/variables) for all the code in this external directory.

To do this, I used `Tools -> CMake -> Change Project Root` and selected the external dir. However, features such as Find Usages do not work properly unless I right-click this external dir's name in the Project view and choose `Mark Directory as -> Project Sources and Headers`. Then, Find Usages works. So, that's good.

However, in order to tell the compiler where function definitions and such are located, I need to manually mention each .cpp file from the external dir in CMakeLists.txt. However, trying to mention any file from the external dir in CMakeLists.txt via a relative path gives the error "Cannot find source file".

The only thing I can do to fix this is use absolute paths:

```
set(SOURCE_FILES /absolute/path/to/external/dir/main.cpp)
```

Is there a better way of doing this? I would think that resetting the project root to the external directory would make using an absolute path in CMakeLists.txt unnecessary.